# Django Session Not Matching Query

Tags: python, django

I want to make user order for services without logging in to do that. I'm using `session` to handle that. whereby user will have to fill a form before being redirected to third party payment website.

I wrote the below codes, it's working fine on development server. Both on Chrome and mozilla. After deploying to production server, I tested it on Chrome, it's working fine, but when I tested it on Mozilla, it will bring out this error:

```
DoesNotExist: Session matching query does not exist.
```

Models:

```
class Pay(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,blank=True, null=True)
    session=models.ForeignKey(Session)
    pub_date=models.DateTimeField()
    esell=models.ForeignKey(Esell)
    full_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email_ad=models.EmailField(verbose_name="Email")
    phone_num=models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.full_name, self.esell)
```

Views for accepting user data

```
@csrf_exempt
def pay_dig(request,esellid):
    if request.method=="POST":
        form=PayForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data=form.cleaned_data
            newpayy=Pay(
                session=Session.objects.get(session_key=request.session._session_key),
                pub_date=datetime.datetime.now(),
                esell=Esell.objects.get(pk=esellid),
                full_name=data['full_name'],
                email_ad=data['email_ad'],
                phone_num=data['phone_num'])
            newpayy.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/confirm_payment/')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Go back and fill the form correctly')
    else:
        return render_to_response('pay.html',{'PayForm':PayForm},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Views for redirecting after filling the above form

```
def confam_pay(request):
    return render_to_response('after_pay_form.html',{'newpayy':Pay.objects.filter(session=request.session._session_key).latest('id')},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Template

```
<p><strong> Details</strong> </p>
  <p> Your Name is {{newpayy.full_name }} </p>
<p> Price: N{{ newpayy.esell.up_price }} </p>
<p>  Name Of Product: {{ newpayy.esell.up_name }} </p>
<input type='image'  src='image/file' alt='Make Payment' />
```

What I'm I missing? or is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130639/django-setting-a-session-and-getting-session-key-in-same-view and followed the process. It worked, at least. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what you are doing with the session. Sessions aren't something you create foreign keys to - they might be stored in a db table, but they're ephemeral data associated with a user's current session.

Rather than storing the session in the Pay table, you should store the ID of the Pay model in the session.

**Edit**

Rather than trying to filter based on the session, I would store a list of Pay IDs in the session itself. Then to display purchases you can simply get all the instances by ID.

```
newpayy = Pay(...)
newpayy.save()
pay_list = request.session.setdefault('pay_list', [])
pay_list.append(newpayy.id)
request.session.modified = True
```

and to get the values back:

```
pay_ids = request.session.get('pay_list')
if pay_ids:
    pay_objects = Pay.objects.filter(pk__in=pay_ids)
```

Don't forget, whether you do it my way or your way, sessions are ephemeral and not reliable for long-term storage. If a user logs in or out, clears their cookies, or uses a different machine, the items in the session will be lost.

Comment: How can I store Pay ID in session? :(

Comment: The reason why I used session is that after the user must have paid, upon redirection from the third party payment website, the user will be able to download what he paid for.

Comment: @limelights what did you want me to blog about? I did write something the other week about my fairly obscure AST-parsing vim extension, which I doubt is of interest to anyone but me. Haven't written about Django for a while since, despite my answers here, I'm not really using it on a day-to-day basis at the moment. That might change soon though.

Comment: @picomon you can do `request.session['pay_id'] = newpayy.id` after saving it and then get the ID back from `request.session['pay_id']` when the user wants to download.

Comment: So with your answer, it means I should remove session from models, session=models.ForeignKey(Session) and this from views. session=Session.objects.get(session_key=request.session._session_key). Will I be able to filter the data submitted by the user after payment?

Comment: Don't forget that it's not important for the user to login before making payemnt. Will it still work? :)

Comment: @DanielRoseman Nah, I don't know but I do enjoy reading your blog from time to time! Always love reading about people using Django. I would blog myself but I suck at writing and I suck even more at Django so a blog from me would be pointless :)